# Is there anyway to make an EditText start typing at the top left corner of the EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, center, typing

I have an `EditText` with the property:

```
android:minLines="3"
```

However, when I start typing, it types in the middle of the `EditText`.

Is there any way to get this to start typing at the top left of the `EditText` area?

Comment: Try this perfect solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47813929/3448003

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="top|left"` to the `EditText` in the layout XML file.

Comment: @Commons Ware what should i need to do if i want my edittext hint in center_vertical but it should start typing from top|left ?

Comment: @Erum: I am not aware of a way to control the positioning of the hint independently of the positioning of the text.

Comment: Use start or end rather than left and right these days to compensate for both RTL and LTR readers

Answer (score 4):

Just insert

```
android:gravity="top"
```

into your EditText.

Answer (score 4):

`android:gravity="start"` would put it to the top left.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. Try this EditText....

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_comment_note"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/white_box"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Note"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```